# How animate objets seperately?

Tags: opengl

I've set up a simple scene with some triangle and quads. With  `glPushMatrix()` and  `glPopMatrix()` i achieved to move an object to a new position, relative to another object in my render scene, but what i want is, for example, that the first triangle translates every render() call -2 units on the z axis, but the other triangle translates only -1 unit. I couldn't find any information how to manage this. As yet every `glTranslatef()` affects all objets. So what I have to do?

Answer (score 1):

First stop using the fixed function pipeline. It's deprecated and removed from new versions; shaders is the new kid on the block.

With shaders you have a Matrixes stored in each object and you only need to set the applicable uniform to it and use it in the vertex shader.

Using the old fixed function the solution is push and pop the matrix for each object separately:

```
glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(...);
    renderTriangle();
glPopMatrix();

glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(...);
    renderTriangle();
glPopMatrix();
```

Comment: I've yet done it this way. After initialization, the triangles have the same z-axis value, they are parallel. In the render function, i put the code as you described. Now one triangle is on another position. Actually I could get the same result by set these coordinates from the beginning. But what I want is, that every render() call, there is a move, like -1 unit on tri1 and -2 on tri2. With this code, the distance between the triangles remains at the same level. The `glTranslatef(...)`call at the beginning affects all triangles the same way.

Answer (score 0):

To add onto ratchet freak's answer, the modern way to do this now is to use a [vertex buffer object.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_Buffer_Object). Basically, you create a buffer which stores the vertex data and can be modified every frame with the new vertex data, which is then drawn with `glDrawArrays` or `glDrawElements`. This way is also fast because you're drawing all the vertex data in a single draw call (which changes once you have to bind multiple textures). You can then easily modify the vertex data in any way you desire. The downfall is that it's a bit hard to set everything up and get it running, but the end result is definitely worth it.

I recommend [Lazyfoo's tutorial on the subject](http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/OpenGL/17_vertex_buffer_objects/index.php), it's what I used when I was learning about it (as well as general googling).